# How to fix the encoding of a requirements.txt file on macOS?

Tags: macos, encoding, pip, requirements.txt

I am working under macOS Monterey 12.4 and trying to open my `requirements.txt` file got by `pip3 freeze > requirements.txt` command in terminal with TextEdit. That gives me a few lines of hieroglyphs [looking so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xp3J6.png), and further tries to change the encoding through TextEdit settings to any other one bring me no result: the text in file doesn't change at all. I've discovered with `file -I requirements.txt` that the encoding of my file is `utf-16le` but it makes no difference to me for the reason named before. What am I doing wrong?

Steps I made were the next:

1. Create a file with `pip3 freeze > requirements.txt`
2. Open the file in TextEdit
3. Get stuff
4. Change encoding in TextEdit through Settings > "Opening Files" (under Plain Text Encoding) to any random
5. See no changes
6. Get `charset=utf-16le` with `file -I requirements.txt`
7. Repeat steps 4-5 choosing "Unicode (UTF-16LE)" namingly
8. Still have no positive results

**UPD 1** attached hex dump of the file:

```
00000000: 636f 6e74 6f75 7270 793d 3d31 2e31 2e31  contourpy==1.1.1
00000010: 0a63 7963 6c65 723d 3d30 2e31 322e 310a  .cycler==0.12.1.
00000020: 666f 6e74 746f 6f6c 733d 3d34 2e34 372e  fonttools==4.47.
00000030: 320a 696d 706f 7274 6c69 622d 7265 736f  2.importlib-reso
00000040: 7572 6365 733d 3d36 2e31 2e31 0a6b 6977  urces==6.1.1.kiw
00000050: 6973 6f6c 7665 723d 3d31 2e34 2e35 0a6d  isolver==1.4.5.m
00000060: 6174 706c 6f74 6c69 623d 3d33 2e37 2e34  atplotlib==3.7.4
00000070: 0a6e 756d 7079 3d3d 312e 3234 2e34 0a70  .numpy==1.24.4.p
```

**UPD 2** `locale` outputs:

```
LANG="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

**UPD 3**
I've discovered that VSCode suddenly displays my `requirements.txt` in a correct way and got into stuck. How is to deal with the same case next time?

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. I see the same symbols. Thank you a lot for the answer anyway.

Comment: Can you post a sample of `hieroglyphs` ?

Comment: It'd also help to have at least a partial hex dump of the file, to see exactly what's in there. Try `xxd -l 128 requirements.txt`, and edit your question to include the output (in [code block format](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361), so it's readable).

Comment: On my system `pip3 freeze` outputs a plain text file (which is what I would expect). It certainly isn't expected to output UTF-16LE encoded text. Something is very wrong with your system or you haven't accurately reported the commands you ran. Go back to step one. Run `pip3 freeze | head -2 | od -tx1`. Substitute `xxd -l 128` for `od -tx1` if you have the `xxd` command installed. Then copy/paste the output into your problem statement.

Comment: Also, tell us what `locale` outputs on your system.

Comment: Added it all: 1. a screenshot of hieroglyphs; 2. the hex dump; 3. the locale output.

Comment: The hex dump shows it's perfectly fine ASCII. For some reason, TextEdit and `file` are just guessing wrong.

Comment: I'v discovered that VSCode displays my requirements.txt correctly. The questions then are: 1) How often do such mistakes with TextEdit and `file` happen; 2) How to understand, which one file reader / decoder should I trust?